# Trying to read a UTF-8 XML file with Python 3

Tags: xml, python-3.x, encoding, python-3.6

I am trying to read an **UTF-8 XML file** with **Python 3** but I am really in trouble with the encoding:

```
In [47]: fileObj = codecs.open(file, "r", "utf-8")

In [48]: fileObj.read()
Out[48]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-dd7cd49f4aa8> in <module>()
----> 1 fileObj.read()

~/Documents/Projects/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.py in __call__(self, result)
    259             self.fill_exec_result(result)
    260             if format_dict:
--> 261                 self.write_format_data(format_dict, md_dict)
    262                 self.log_output(format_dict)
    263             self.finish_displayhook()

~/Documents/Projects/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.py in write_format_data(self, format_dict, md_dict)
    188                 result_repr = '\n' + result_repr
    189 
--> 190         print(result_repr)
    191 
    192     def update_user_ns(self, result):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u20ac' in position 1630: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Where I am wrong?

Comment: You are reading ok. Just assign it to a variable. It is a IPython's display hook that is failing.  You likely don't have your terminal encoding configured correctly.  Also `codecs.open` is unnecessary and can be buggy. `open` works fine in Python3.

Answer (score 0):

Mark is right, my problem is on iPython.

I solved setting the `PYTHONIOENCODING` env variable to `utf-8`:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING="utf-8"
```

Thanks!